# Connect 2 earbuds iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone, audio

Need ability for 2 people to listen to my iPhone 6S at the same time. Visiting museum while traveling. Tried finding spliters online. Only find ones the have charging and listening, not 2 sets of listening.

Comment: Are you open to sharing AirPods?

Answer (score 1):

The 6S has a 3.5mm audio jack. There are many splitters available for that on any site that sells them.

E.g. https://www.walmart.com/search/?cat_id=0&query=3.5mm+audio+splitter

Comment: I have about 4 on my shelf - my kids use and loose them often... Just perfect for that job and cheap...